# Why using nC2*1/365 to calculate the birthday paradox is incorrect

Tags: algorithms, hash, mathematical-analysis

The birthday paradox is basically that assume there are 365 days in a year(ignore the effect of Febuary 29th), each person's birthday is uniformly random in these 365 days and independent with others. How many people do we need to have a more than 50% chance that two persons(or more) have the same birthday.

my understanding is that, the probability that two people have the same birthday is: the probability that they have the same birthday on day1 is 1/365*1/365, the probability that they have the same birthday on day2 is 1/365*1/365 and so on. so the probability that they have the same birthday is (1/365*1/365)*365=1/365.

assume there are n people, so 2 out of n, we have nC2 pairs of people, which is n(n-1)/2. so the probability that one pair of these people have the same birthday is n(n-1)/2*(1/365), let it equals to 1/2, then I get n to be around 19. but the correct answer is 23, and they are using permutation instead of combination. I don't know how to understand that.

Comment: Here's a way to see that you must be wrong: your method, multiplying the probability an individual pair having the same birthday by the number of pairs, would give a "probability" larger that 1 if you had more than 365 people in your room. If you want to fix your argument you need to think harder about how it is supposed to work: why exactly would you add the individual pair probabilities? What probability law are you using? (The probability of the union of two events is *not* the sum of their probabilities...)

Comment: (`*` is special in *Markdown* (the language used for posts (and comments)): "Escape" it like `\*`.)

Comment: you are overcounting. lets take 3 people A, B, C. So you have 4 combinations AB, AC, BC and ABC (so its not simply nc2 * 1/365), since it's mentioned at least 2 people should have the same birthday. Use the principle of inclusion exclusion and figure out for which event calculating the probability would be easier.